# Processo de desenvolvimento com Docker

Tags: docker

Eu entendo o conceito básico do Docker e suas vantagens porém tenho dúvidas de como é usado no processo de desenvolvimento, essas dúvidas são:

- Tecnicamente o Docker gera "snapshot da máquina" então todos os
  desenvolvedores obrigatoriamente puxam do mesmo hub para não ter
  diferença no container correto?
- Esse container está na máquina de todos os desenvolvedores do time ou
  em um servidor externo?
- Eu codifico na minha máquina e "faço deploy" no container somente
  depois do desenvolvimento?
- O ambiente de homologação continua sendo utilizado após o Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma resposta de cada vez:

> Tecnicamente o Docker gera "snapshot da máquina" então todos os desenvolvedores obrigatoriamente puxam do mesmo hub para não ter diferença no container correto?

Exatamente. Esse *snapshot da máquina* que é chamado de ***container***. Nele container tem todo ambiente necessário para rodar o seu serviço.

> Esse container está na máquina de todos os desenvolvedores do time ou em um servidor externo?

Isso varia muito no workflow de cada equipe. O container geralmente é o produto final do processo de desenvolvimento, no sentido de ele ter toda a capacidade de *rodar o serviço apenas com um comando*, e é ele que também vai para produção.

> Eu codifico na minha máquina e "faço deploy" no container somente depois do desenvolvimento?

Sim, o que você está procurando é o *Automated Builds*, que é um recurso do *Dockerhub* que permite que você alinhe um repositório do Github com um container, fazendo um processo muito parecido com o de uma integração contínua, sendo que a cada commit o *Dockerhub* irá tentar fazer um *docker build*, com o *Dockerfile* presente na raiz do repositório.

> O ambiente de homologação continua sendo utilizado após o Docker?

Uma das vantagens do Docker é justamente a de poder rodar o ambiente de homologação em sua máquina, ou de recuperar facilmente ele caso ocorra algo errado. Porém isso não exclui a necessidade de ter um ambiente de homologação, é sempre importante testar e validar os serviços e se os containers estão rodando de acordo.

A sua dúvida claramente não é de Docker, e sim de ***Devops***. Que engloba também o Docker e outros conceitos, que fazem uso do Docker, como Integração Contínua e Entrega contínua.

O *Devops* permitiu ter um processo de entrega automatizado e mais ágil. Recomendo dar uma olhada nesse conceito, pois ele engloba o uso do Docker em produção. Alguns links interessantes:

- [Whitepaper Docker and The Three Ways of DevOps](https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/WP_Docker%20and%20the%203%20ways%20devops_07.31.2015%20(1).pdf)
- [DevOps Wiki](https://github.com/Leo-G/DevopsWiki)

Answer (score 3):

Baseado em minha experiência com Docker:

- A obrigatoriedade de usar ou não Docker no processo de Desenvolvimento depende do processo estabelecido. Por exemplo, no meu processo tenho uma base_container contendo todas as dependências de um Projeto (como ruby + sinatra). A partir dai tenho 2 processos, um como meu ambiente de dev e outro de builds (para Homologação ou Produção). No ambiente de dev utilizo a base_container e monto os volumes com código do projeto. No processo de build uso CI para gerar os containers finais e a partir deles jogo em Produção.
- Os containers normalmente ficam armazenados em servidores: Docker Registry para servidor Interno ou DockerHub contratado como serviço.
- Sim, idealmente faça em processos diferentes .. como no exemplo da resposta 1. Geralmente um container de Dev é poluído com instalações manuais, arquivos de testes, arquivos de configuração modificados de forma aleatória, coisas do tipo ... Mas nada impede que possa gerar tags a partir de uma maquina de desenvolvedor, depende do processo estabelecido.
- O ambiente de Homologação é importante caso precise consolidar a entrega de diversos projetos, codigos, containers .. ou quando possui um time grande de desenvolvedores e precise agrupar todas as mudanças antes de levar para um ambiente de produção. Particularmente eu começaria a observar Continuous Delivery e BlueGreen Deployment de forma que seja possível encurtar o tempo entre os commits e deploys em produção.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, tomando como exemplo o processo que venho utilizando:

Geralmente são geradas imagens customizadas(a partir de `Dockerfiles`) para atender as necessidades de cada serviço da aplicação, como por exemplo os serviços web, servidor de banco de dados e servidor de caching, A partir destas imagens, cada qual gerando seu próprio container. E a utilização do *docker-composer* para orquestração de todos serviços, facilitando o set-up do ambiente todo.

Para fins práticos, em ambiente de desenvolvimento, *espelhamos* o código-fonte da aplicação através de *Volumes* do Docker dentro de seus respectivos containers, assim cada desenvolvedor executa a *build* das imagens e roda o seu container, localmente, com sua versão do projeto. Então teoricamente você desenvolve na sua máquina, porém com resultados sendo refletidos em tempo real no seu container.

Já para o ambiente de QA, produção e afins, dá-se a utilização de um repositório de imagens(como *DockerHub*, ou um *DockerRegistry* privado) onde não mais espelhamos o código-fonte no container, mas apenas o embutimos dentro dele. O processo de deploy a partir daí se torna basicamente um *pull*, em seu servidor, da imagem correspondente.

O grande benefício do Docker é a facilidade de se reproduzir as mesmas condições do ambiente de produção em qualquer outra máquina, mas isso não exclui a necessidade de ambientes de homologação e isso vai do processo de desenvolvimento de cada projeto.